# $15$-th Cyclotomic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

Recall that the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{n,K}(x)$ associated with a field $K$ (with characteristic coprime with $n$) is $\prod_{1\leq j\leq n, (j,n) = 1}(x - \omega^j)$ where $\omega$ is a generator of the group $\mu_n(L) = \{\alpha \in L: \alpha^n = 1\}$, with $L$ being a splitting field of $x^n - 1 \in K[x]$. Treat that $\omega$ always exists and that $\Phi_{n,K} \in K[x]$, without proof.

Find all prime numbers $p \neq 3,5$ such that $\Phi_{15,\mathbb{Q}}(x) \pmod p = \Phi_{15,\mathbb{F}_p}(x)$.

I know the Galois structure in $\mathbb{Q}$ for $n = 15$ (the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z}$ is $C_2 \times C_4$, generated by $2$ and $11$ for example) and also an explicit form for the polynomial in this case, but have no idea if any of this is useful.

I can also independently show that the $\mathbb{Q}$ polynomial is reducible $\pmod p$ for every $p \neq 3,5$.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Since $\deg(\Phi_{15,\Bbb Q})=8$, you’re looking for $p$ such that $\deg(\Phi_{15,\Bbb F_p})=8$ as well. Now, for the latter degree to be eight, it means that adjoining a fifteenth root of unity to $\Bbb F_p$ would give you an $8$-degree field extension. That means exactly that $15|(p^8-1)$ and (since the biggest proper divisor of $8$ is $4$) at the same time that $15$ does *not* divide $p^4-1$. In other words, we are seeking $p$ such that $p^8\equiv1$ but $p^4\not\equiv1\pmod{15}$.

But we’ve got a problem here: as you know, *every* number $m$ prime to $15$ has $m^4\equiv1\pmod{15}$.

Thus it would seem that there are no such $p$.

---

**EDIT**:
I finally realize that we were communicating at cross purposes. You want a polynomial that catches all and only the primitive $15$-th roots of unity; I was wanting a minimal polynomial for such a root of unity.

But then the answer to your question is simple: irrespective of characteristic (avoiding $p=3,5$), the polynomial you’re looking for is always
$$
\frac{(X^{15}-1)(X-1)}{(X^5-1)(X^3-1)}\quad=\quad X^8-X^7+X^5-X^4+X^3-X+1\,.
$$

Comment: Adjoining a 15th root would give you a degree 8 extension only if we know that $\Phi_{15,\mathbb{F}_p}$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F_p}$. Is this always true, I would guess not?

Comment: Correct. Therefore, there is no “$\Phi_{15,\Bbb F_p}$”: the primitive $15$-th roots of unity fall into at least two classes, in which the elements are Galois conjugates of each other. Each such class is stable under the operation $x\mapsto x^p$, the Frobenius. Extreme example: $k=\Bbb F_{31}$, in which the $15$-th roots of unity all are already in $k$, so $\Phi_{15,\Bbb Q}$ factors into linears modulo $31$.

Comment: And at the opposite extreme is $p=2$, where the $\Bbb Q$, $15$-cyclotomic factors as $(x^4+x^3+1)(x^4+x+1)$, two irreducible quartics. But you’ll never get an irreducible octic. The reason, I suppose, is that the $3$-cyclotomic field and the $5$-cyclotomic field are linearly disjoint extensions of $\Bbb Q$, whereas in char. $p$, *the* quadratic field and *the* quartic field are necessarily never linearly disjoint. indeed the former is always contained in the latter.

Comment: Wait, how does all this imply that "there is no $\Phi_{15,\mathbb{F}_p}$"? Which part of the assumptions I have given breaks down?

Comment: Because different primitive $15$-th roots of unity may easily have different minimal polynomials. And there’s no minimal polynomial that catches them all. In the least bad situation, typified by $p=2$, there are two $\Phi$’s; in the worst situation, typified by $p=31$, there are eight of them.

Comment: But nobody insists on $\Phi$ being irreducible so that you say "at $p=2$ there are two irreducible factors so there are two $\Phi$-s", similarly for 31